# Why is the custom taxonomy archive page redirecting me to a single post?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, archives, archive-template

I have a custom taxonomy, *artist*, that is related to three custom post types: *videos*, *posts* and *letters*. I have an `taxonomy-artist.php` template that should display the archive for a given artist.

When I visit `/artist/ARTIST_NAME` it will display the taxonomy archive template *only if there are no other posts associated with it*. If there *are* posts associated with it, you get redirected to an individual post (I believe it's the oldest post associated with the taxonomy term). So if I visit `/artist/ARTIST_NAME` and there is content associated with it, I get kicked out to `[videos|letters|posts]/THE_POST_NAME`.

I saw something about needing to have taxonomies registered before custom post types, so I am registering the taxonomy first and I've flushed out my permalink settings, but no luck. I'm stumped as to why this would be happening, so I would appreciate any ideas about what would cause this!

Here's the code I'm using for registering the taxonomy and post types:

```
register_taxonomy( 'artist',
    array(
        'videos',
        'letters',
        'post'
    ),
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => _x( 'Artists', 'taxonomy general name' ),
            'singular_name' => _x( 'Artist', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
            'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Artists' ),
            'all_items' => __( 'All Artists' ),
            'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Artist' ),
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Artist:' ),
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Artist' ),
            'update_item' => __( 'Update Artist' ),
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Artist' ),
            'new_item_name' => __( 'New Artist Name' ),
            'menu_name' => __( 'Artists' ),
        )
    )
);

register_post_type( 'letters',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Letters' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Letter' )
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' ),
        'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/img/mail.png',
    )
);

register_post_type( 'videos',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Videos' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Video' )
        ),
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' ),
        'public' => true,
        'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/img/blue-document-film.png',
    )
);
```

Comment: Can you post your relevant `register_post_type()`, `register_taxonomy()`, and `register_taxonomy_for_object_type()` code?

Comment: Sure thing @ChipBennett! I just updated the question with the code that is registering the taxonomies and post types.

Comment: Does anything change if you disable rewrites (use default permalinks)?

Comment: @ChipBennett - Nope. I just tried it and it still kicks me out to a single post when visiting a taxonomy archive page.

Comment: Other things to try: call `register_taxonomy()` *after* `register_post_type()`; add taxonomy support inside the `register_post_type()` call itself (though I doubt either of these is the issue, if you are able to apply the taxonomy to all applicable post types); for testing purposes, apply the taxonomy only to *one* custom post type, and then see if the taxonomy archive index works as expected.

Comment: @ChipBennett - Thanks for the ideas. I tried everything, but still having the same issue. Tried moving around the methods, specifying the taxonomy in the post type declaration and applying the taxonomy to only a single post type... Still nothing. I also flushed the permalinks between updates.

Answer (score 1):

Taxonomy archive index pages for custom taxonomies are not rendered using `archive-{taxonomy}.php`, but rather, using `taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php`, which falls back to `taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php`, which falls back to `taxonomy.php`. [Refer to the Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display).

WordPress interprets `archive-{foobar}.php` as `archive-{post-type}.php`, and would use that template to render the archive index for the `foobar` **post-type**. So, your `artist` taxonomy archive index page will never be rendered using `archive-artist.php`.

**Try renaming the template file to `taxonomy-artist.php`.**

Comment: Crap, I'm sorry... I actually am using `taxonomy-artist.php`, I just wasn't thinking. I will revise my question. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured this out. It turns out the original author of the theme was overriding this. My setup was correct, I just had to remove the overrides.